# PostgreSQL - Alternate for like in, contains

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to do a pattern matching but for multiple values, something like:

```
select *
from account as a
where lower(a.name) like in ('aria1%', 'beta5%')
```

Off course, the one above is not working.

---

Regarding comments bellow
I didn't used 'OR' or proposed regex, because is done, in code, and I have some constrains. So the solution with the `array` is the best option in my case.Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using `or`?

Comment: Another alternative is `LIKE ANY(ARRAY['aria1%', 'beta5%'])`

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is to just use `or`:

```
select *
from account as a
where lower(a.name) like 'aria1%' or
      lower(a.name) like 'beta5%';
```

Regular expressions are another method:

```
where a.name ~ '^(aria1|beta5)'
```